# How to use SVG with grunt and jade

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gruntjs

I am using svg files for my projects and I like to have them 'in-line' in the html so that I can use css/js to fiddle with them.

I have 2 problems with this approach:

- I am using jade templating engine so I have to convert the xml to jade before adding them
- it really messes up my jade file adding a lot of xml code

So far the way I load my svg icons is the following: I put them in an `assets` folder and load them in jade like this:

```
          div
            img(src='/assets/svg/my_icon.svg')
```

But here, I cannot use js/css to style them.

Is there any way, using Grunt for example, to look up in my assets folder, grab the xml and populate my html code with it?

Comment: I don't know Jade, but could you include CSS/JS inside the SVG ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this is to use [grunt-svgstore](https://github.com/FWeinb/grunt-svgstore) with the following settings in the Gruntfile.js

```
svgstore: {
  default:{
    options: {
      prefix : 'icon-', // This will prefix each ID,
      svg: { // will add and overide the the default xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attribute to the resulting SVG
        viewBox : '0 0 100 100',
        xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      }
    },
    files: {
      "<%= folders.src %>/jade/_svgDef.jade": ["<%= folders.src %>/svg/*.svg"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: I'm compiling all of the SVGs in my folder directly into one **jade** file, that I include in my layout.jade like so:

```
.svgdef(style="display:none;")
  include _svgDef
```

For any SVG, grunt-svgstore creates nice IDs for you to include:

```
svg(viewBox="0 0 100 100", xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    use(xlink:href="#icon-Twitter")
```

Which is cool, because now you can style this SVG within your CSS, while keeping your edited jade files free from clutter!